# How to Convert Point to Points?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing a Win32 Program.

```
    POINTS p = MAKEPOINTS(lParam); 

    ClientToScreen(hWnd, &p);
```

How do I convert `p` to a `POINT` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POINT` and `POINTS` are not the same thing.  So you will have to either:

1. copy the `POINTS` to a separate `POINT`:

   ```
   POINTS ps = MAKEPOINTS(lParam); 
   POINT pt;
   pt.x = ps.x;
   pt.y = ps.y;
   ClientToScreen(hWnd, &pt);
   ```
2. get rid of the `POINTS` altogether and just use `POINT` by itself:

   ```
   POINT pt;
   pt.x = GET_X_PARAM(lParam);
   pt.y = GET_Y_PARAM(lParam);
   ClientToScreen(hWnd, &pt);
   ```

Answer (score 5):

It's just a POINT with [shorts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of [longs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so this should work:

```
POINT pt = {p.x, p.y};
```

Alternatively, it seems there's actually a [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this as well:

```
POINT pt;
POINTSTOPOINT(pt, p);
```